# Sunspot Solr Reindexing failing due to illegal characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, rubygems, rsolr

I'm having an issue where Solr is failing to reindex my site, due to the following error from my production log:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request
Error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 12))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [155,1]
```

I am not sure where this 'illegal character' is being generated from, nor where to find this. I more than appreciate everyone's help, as it is causing a 500 server error on my app right now. Thank you, and let me know if more information is needed.

(Rails 3.2)
(Rsolr 1.0.10)

Comment: I later found out that I had installed a wrong version of sunspot in my app. Go figure... Once I bundled again with the correct version, all was well in the world.

Comment: What version were you using and what did you switch too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is caused by bad data in your database.  If you're using MySQL you can find any instances of control character 12 with a query like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE col REGEXP CHAR(12);`

Then you can remove the character from the content of any matched rows & proceed to reindex.

You could also do something like this to remove the control characters:

`UPDATE table SET col=REPLACE(col, CHAR(12), '') WHERE col REGEXP CHAR(12);`